# How to use the 'eachLine' closure from a BufferedReader?

Tags: file-io, groovy, fileinputstream

It seems groovy has a nice closure that works off Java io's file object to read the lines from a data file (say tab-delmited text for example)..

```
def inputFile = new File('me/documents/100reasonsIloveJenniferLawerence.txt');
inputFile.eachLine { rawLine ->

def line = rawLine.split('\t')
```

But supposing the file is 'UTF-16LE' encoded and the File constructor does not allow for the encoding to be specified and so I need to use BufferedReader like so...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream('me/documents/100reasonsIloveJenniferLawerence.txt'), "UTF-16LE"));
```

Can I still use eachLine with this BufferedReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

I assume you didn't bother to try?

But

```
reader.eachLine { line ->
    println line
}
```

Will work fine

Or you can skip all that, and just pass the charset to eachLine:

```
inputfile.eachLine('UTF-16LE') { line ->
```